# Google Maps JavaScript API & Static Maps API Keys

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

We are using Google Maps JavaScript API and Static Maps API in our application. Currently we plan to go with the Standard plan and then enable the billing based on the usage in Production.
Just wanted to clarify if we can use the same API_KEY for both JavaScript API and Static Maps API. Are there any restrictions on whether API_KEY can be used only for JavaScript API or Static Maps API?

Regards,
Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same API key for both Maps JavaScript API and Static Maps API. You can additionally set HTTP referer restrictions to the API key if you wish. Maybe if you use these APIs on different domains you might be interested in creation of separate keys on per domain basis for tracking purposes. Anyway this is your choice.